# Boolean functions built from $\wedge$ and $\vee$

Tags: boolean-algebra

Prove that not every Boolean function is equal to a Boolean function constructed by only $\wedge$ and $\vee$. Please can you help me giving some hint.

Comment: This question was asked here recently: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/707337/every-boolean-function-is-constructed-from-wedges-and-vees#comment1501826_707337

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the Boolean functions constructed with only $\wedge$ and $\vee$ are nondecreasing in all variables.

Answer (score 0):

Both functions preserve $1$. So if you have some formula with variables $x_1 \ldots x_n$ and if all of them are equal to $1$, the result is also equal to $1$.